# Adding two parameters in HTTP Post

Tags: angular

I am trying to send two values from client to server side using HTTP post in MEAN. I can add one but when I try to add two values I am getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
var emailid = 'emailid=' + ctinvite.emp_email;
var phone= 'phone=' + ctinvite.emp_phone;
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded');
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendmail',emailid, {headers: headers})
```

I added emailid and it's working perfectly. Now I want to add phone along with emailid in HTTP Post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will to create an url with params like this:

`http://url.com/user?emailid=12&phone=2234234234`

than you should use `HttpParams` (or `URLSearchParams` for old (<4.3) Angular version). [Here](https://angular.io/guide/http#url-parameters) you can find a little bit more.

Here is an example based on your question data:

Angular v4.3+ with new HttpClientModule:

```
let httpParams = new HttpParams();
httpParams = httpParams.set('emailid', ctinvite.emp_email.toString());
httpParams = httpParams.set('phone', ctinvite.emp_phone.toString());
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded');
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendmail', null, {headers: headers, params: httpParams});
```

Angular v4.3 and older with old HttpModule:

```
let params = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('emailid', ctinvite.emp_email.toString());
params.set('phone', ctinvite.emp_phone.toString());
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded');
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendmail', null, {search: params, headers: headers});
```

If you will to send you data as `FormData` (that I see on your headers settings) so here is an example for that:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('emailid', ctinvite.emp_email.toString());
formData.append('phone', ctinvite.emp_phone.toString());
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded');
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendmail',formData, {headers: headers});
```

If you will to send you data as JSON object, so you should make it like this:

```
let jsonData = {
  emailid: ctinvite.emp_email,
  phone: ctinvite.emp_phone
}
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendmail', JSON.stringify(jsonData), {headers: headers});
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using a complex object as below

```
var emailid = 'emailid=' + ctinvite.emp_email;
var phone= 'phone=' + ctinvite.emp_phone;\
var email_phone ={
    emailid : emailid,
    phone :phone
}
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded');
this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/sendmail',email_phone, {headers: headers})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code :

```
var emailid = 'emailid=' + ctinvite.emp_email;
var phone= 'phone=' + ctinvite.emp_phone;
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded');
this.http.post(`http://localhost:3000/sendmail=${emailid}&phone=${phone}`, {headers: headers})
```

Hope it will help

Comment: adding query params in post is not advisable

Comment: rather you can wrap objects in single structure, and pass that object in the post request.

Comment: Can you send your api code then I can help you better. The best way to send data in post is to send in the body of the request. If you are getting your data in api in a single object then obviously you need to send an object in the body of the request.